# Numerical Recipes lubksb routine not working

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, physics, inverse

Context: I am writing a code in order to solve the Lippmann-Schwinger equation and verify experimental results after using different potentials.
In order to do this I have to compute the inverse of a sparse and large matrix. I am using NR routines ludcmp and lubksb but something is not right. After ludcmp the matrix has many zeros and lubksb computes the vector b as b[i]/a[i][j], generating -nan most of the time. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for the help!

Here is the portion of my code daling with matrix inversion.

```
    //lu decomp algorithm
    void ludcmp(double **a, int n, int *indx, double d)
    {
     int i,imax,j,k;
     double big,dum,sum,temp;
      double *vv;    //vv stores the implicit scaling of each row.
      vv= new double[n];//vector(1,n);
      d=1.0; //No row interchanges yet.

      for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
      {//Loop over rows to get the implicit scaling information.
       big=0.0;
       for (j=0;j<n;j++)
       if ((temp=fabs(a[i][j])) > big) big=temp;
       //char const *p = "Singular matrix in routine ludcmp"; //
       if (big == 0.0) std::cout<<("Singular matrix in routine ludcmp");                            
       //No nonzero largest element.
       vv[i]=1.0/big; //Save the scaling.
      }

      for (j=0;j<n;j++)
      {//This is the loop over columns of Crout’s method.
       for (i=0;i<j;i++) 
       {//This is equation (2.3.12) except for i=j.
       sum=a[i][j];
       for (k=0;k<i;k++) sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
       a[i][j]=sum;
       }

       big=0.0;
       //Initialize for the search for largest pivot element.
       for (i=j;i<n;i++) 
       {//This is i=j of equation (2.3.12) and i = j+1...N
        sum=a[i][j];
        for (k=0;k<j-1;k++)
        sum -= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
        a[i][j]=sum;
        if ( (dum=vv[i]*fabs(sum)) >= big) 
        {//Is the figure of merit for the pivot 
          better than the best so          far?
         big=dum;
         imax=i;
        }
                         }

       if (j != imax) 
       {//Do we need to interchange rows?
        for (k=0;k<n;k++) 
        {//Yes, do so...
         dum=a[imax][k];
         a[imax][k]=a[j][k];
         a[j][k]=dum;
        }
        d = -d;  //...and change the parity of d.
        vv[imax]=vv[j]; //Also interchange the scale factor.
       }

       indx[j]=imax;
       if (a[j][j] == 0.0) a[j][j]=TINY;
       /*If the pivot element is zero the matrix is singular 
       (at least to  the precision of the algorithm). 
       For some applications on singular matrices, 
       it is desirable to  substitute TINY for zero.*/
       if (j != n) 
       {//Now, finally, divide by the pivot element.
        dum=1.0/(a[j][j]);
        for (i=j+1;i<n;i++) a[i][j] *= dum;
       }
      }
      //Go back for the next column in the reduction.

        delete[] vv;
     }

     void lubksb(double **a, int n, int *indx, double b[])
     {
      int i,ii=0,ip,j;
      double sum;
      //for (i=1;i<n;i++) 
      for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      {//When ii is set to a positive value, 
      it will become the index of the first nonvanishing 
      element of b.
       //We now do the forward substitution, equation (2.3.6).
     //The only new wrinkle is to unscramble
     //the permutation as we go.
       ip=indx[i];
       sum=b[ip];
       b[ip]=b[i];
       if (ii)
       for (j=ii;j<i-1;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j];
       else if (sum) ii=i;
       //A nonzero element was encountered, 
       //so from now on we will have to do the sums in the loop above.
       b[i]=sum;
      }
      //for (i=n-2;i>(-1);i--) 
      for (i=n-1;i>=0;i--) 
      {//Now we do the backsubstitution, equation (2.3.7).
       sum=b[i];
       for (j=i+1;j<n;j++) sum -= a[i][j]*b[j]; 
       b[i]=sum/a[i][i];
       //Store a component of the solution vector X.
      }
         for(int i=0; i<n; i++) std::cout<< 
     "b["<<i<<"]= "<<b[i]<<std::endl;
     }


     //matrix inversion

     void invmat(double **a, double **y, int N, int *indx, double *b,          double d)
     {
      ludcmp(a,N,indx,d);
      std::ofstream oo; oo.open("invmattttt.txt",std::ios::out);
      oo<< "after lu dec" << std::endl;
      for(int i=0; i< N; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<N; j++) oo << "a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]= " << a[i][j] << std::endl;
      //Decompose the matrix just once.
      //for(int j=1;j<=N;j++) 
      for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
      {
      //Find inverse by columns.
      //for(int i=1;i<=N;i++) b[i]=0.0;
      for(int i=0;i<N;i++) b[i]=0.0;
      b[j]=1.0;
      lubksb(a,N,indx,b);
      oo<< "\n\nafter lubksb" << std::endl;
      for(int i=0; i< N; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<N; j++) oo <<"a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]= " << a[i][j] <<          std::endl;
      //for(int i=1;i<N;i++) {y[i][j]=b[i]; std::clog<<i<<std::endl;}          std::clog<<"hey there"<<std::endl;
      for(int i=0;i<(N);i++) {y[i][j]=b[i];}}
      oo<< "\n\nafter all" << std::endl;
      for(int i=0; i< N; i++)
         for(int j=0; j<N; j++) oo << y[i][j] << std::endl;
     }
```

Comment: So, you're saying you have a matrix with a lot of zeros and then you divide a vector with elements from the matrix?

Comment: That's what I understood studying the inversion routine for sparse matrices, but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Why don't you simply take some distribution of LAPACK and use that, it's much easier than writing your own code (and possibly faster), not to mention it will force you to optimise the way you store your matrices (assuming they are not stored contiguously right now).